# rdpcap not reading all the packets

Tags: python

I am using rdpcap(packets.pcap) to read packets into scapy. In wireshark the packets.pcap shows 3001 packets, but in scapy only 2996 packets are only shown. When I inspect, I found that it is exactly the last 6 packets are not read into scapy. Can this be due to some memory issue?

Comment: I do not know why this was marked as -ve. The rdpcap was not reading all the packets from the pcap in my code. In the code there was two instances of rdpcap to load two different pcap files. So just to ensure that it was due to memory issue, I tested with just loading rdpcap for the packets.pcap. Then I could see that the whole packets were loaded properly. Is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The issue was indeed due to the memory. The pcap file that I was reading was actually created from another pcap file and I forgot to close the pcap file packets.pcap